# Fit background image in Elementor section

Tags: css, background-image, elementor

As far as I noticed it's super popular and common problem, but all solutions that I have tried failed at the end.

I have a test-ish website: https://mojastrona.hekko.pl/baltyk-strona-glowna/

And what I can't achieve is to fit the background image to any resolution.

Here are my settings for the elementor section:

[image]

[image]

But that doesn't provide perfect image fit. It is being cut. I tried to add some solutions into .css file, that I have found on the Internet, but none of them works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is next to impossible (within reason).

Let's say your image has dimensions of 4:3. Now what happens if someone looks at your website on a 16:9 monitor? The container (and thus the image) would have to either have some blank space above and below OR to the left and right.

There are several reliable alternatives to getting what you want:

1. Position your image so that the most important pieces of the motive is always present (eg. "center top" so that the text in the top of the image is always visible
2. Add a "min height" to the parent container - the section would be the obvious choice. Playing around with VH/%-units might give you a more reliable result
3. Place your image as a simple image-widget instead of as a background-image. Set the width to 100%. Make sure your section is set to "Full width/no gap". Your image will now always be the full width of the screen, without being shrunk by the parent container.

Obviously #3 comes with several limits, as placing content on top of your image is made much harder.